# How can I delete object in other method in Java?

Tags: java

I wonder how can I remove object in other method, for example I want to delete the `dog` object in `deleteObject` method, but it just deletes the current reference to the object!
Is there any solution or not?

```
public class Main {
    public static void main(String[] args) {
        Dog dog = new Dog("Max");
        deleteObject(dog);
        System.out.println(dog.toString()); //it still exists! I want to remove it
    }

    public static void deleteObject(Dog dog) {
          dog = null; //I want to remove this object but it deletes just this method's reference
    }
}

class Dog {
    private String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: make dog a global variable and it will work fine. But I suggest you can use a singleton pattern if you need better usage of objects.

Comment: What do you mean be "delete"? - free the memory?

Comment: The global is static variable? If I try static Dog dog; it is still desn't work. I tried to use the signletone pattern but in my app it is not the best decision because it uses multithreading

Comment: I want the dog variable in main method be null

Answer (score 2):

In java Object are garbage collected(in your words deleted) by GC. When no active reference to that object exist it is automated process. Moreover you can't be 100% sure that when no reference exist it has been deleted its just request.

Comment: @gennad : by leaving anything with no specified reference the Garbage Collector would remove it as @org.life.java stated.

Answer (score 2):

An object is "deleted" (or more specifically becomes eligible for deletion by the garbage collector) when there are no more references to it. In your example there are 2 references pointing at the same object (the dog reference in your main method and the dog reference in your deleteObject method). When you set dog to null in deleteObject the dog reference in main is still pointing to the object.

You can just set the dog reference to null in main and this will make the object elligible for garbage collection. Or make the dog reference a class variable i.e. declared outside any method - then main and delteObject can work with the same dog reference.

Why do you want to delete the object anyway? At the end of your method, all local references become out of scope anyway and the object will become elligible for garbage collection.

Answer (score 2):

I have a solution, but maybe it is just too overkill for your problem; it involves WeakReferences:

```
public class Pound{
   public static WeakReference<Dog> adopt(String name){
      Dog newDog = new Dog(name);
      dogList.add(newDog);
      return new WeakReference<Dog>(newDog);
   }

   public static void sacrifice(WeakReference<Dog> dogRef){
      Dog sadPuppy = dogRef.get();
      dogList.remove(sadPuppy);
   }

   private static List<Dog> dogList = new ArrayList<Dog>();

   public class Dog{
      public String getName(){
         return this.name;
      }

      private Dog(String name){
         this.name = name;
      }

      private String name;
   }
}
```

The trick here is to make sure that the only strong references to Dog instances are in the Pound class (or are local references to a method), and use WeakReferences everywhere else. That way, when you call the method

```
sacrifice(WeakReference<Dog> dog)
```

from anywhere in your code, you'll be removing the only strong reference to it, making it elligible for GC. So, if you want to dispose of a Dog instance from any method:

```
class Main{
   public static void main(String ... args){
      WeakReference<Dog> max = Pound.adopt("Max");

      //This line prints "Max"
      System.out.println(max.get().getName());
      meanMethod(max);

      //Max is now dead, so you get a NullPointerException
      System.out.println(max.get.getName());
   }

   public static void meanMethod(WeakReference<Dog> dog){
      Pound.sacrifice(dog);
      //From this point, dog is no more ='(
   }
}
```

You can create dog instances in one method and dispose of them in another, as long as you only have one permanent strong reference (in the list where the dogs are being stored), and you provide methods to add and remove them from the list. Of course, this is all useless if you do:

```
Dog strongDog = weakReferenceToDog.get();
```

in your main method.

Also, you have to make checks in every part of your code where you use get() for null values, and you'd need some method for constantly cleaning the ReferenceQueue that holds the dead WeakReferences.

Depending on what you actually intend to do, this could be too much and you'd be better with another solution, or forgetting completely about this, but at least this is the only way I can think of that could work.

Answer (score 0):

```
public class Main {
    static Dog dog = null;
    public static void main(String[] args) {

        dog = new Dog("Max");
        dog = deleteObject(dog); //really unnecessary

        if(dog==null)
        {
            System.out.println("I AM DEAD!");
        }
        else
        {
            System.out.println(dog.toString());
        }
    }

    public static Dog deleteObject(Dog dog) {
        dog = null;

        return dog;
    }
}


class Dog {
    private String name;

    public Dog(String name) {
        this.name=name;
    }

    public String getName() {
        return name;
    }

    public void setName(String name) {
        this.name = name;
    }
}
```

Comment: It won't work...I can't access the class variable in static method

Comment: I can use just static variables but there are 2 references too

Comment: Given how little we know about what he's trying to do, and that he probably still needs to learn a lot, I don't think it's wise to advise such specific, dangerous and often misused "solutions" as the Singleton just yet.

Comment: @Bart I agree. @gennad Code updated. Can you share what are you trying to achieve?